# Ask for credentials in email application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, outlook

I need to make an application in visual studio to retrieve the inbox, sent messages and attachments from an exchange email account, as well as being able to mark as read and delete said messages (An outlook-like application if you will).

I have the code to retrieve the inbox and attachments from outlook, but I need it to be separate from outlook or at least I need it to be able to ask for credentials before it shows me the messages. This is the code I have:

```
Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace OutlookNameSpace =  Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
items = inbox.Items;

//Fills a listbox with the inbox messages
public void fillInboxListBox()
{    
    for (int i = 1; i <= inbox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       //lsbxMessages is a ListBox control 
       lsbxMessages.Items.Add(((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[i]).Subject);
    }                
}

//When an item on the listbox is selected, it loads the mail on a separate rich text box
private void lsbxMessages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //lblSubject is a label where I put the subject of the message
     lblSubject.Text = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).Subject;

     //lblSender this is where I put the sender name and email adress         
     lblSender.Text = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).SenderName + " <" + ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).SenderEmailAddress + ">";

     //I put the body of the email in a richtextbox         
     rtbBody.Text = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).Body;

     //lblDateSent shows the date the message was sent
     lblDateSent.Text = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).SentOn.ToString();

     //rtbReceiver is a rich text box where I show all the adresses the email was sent to
     rtbReceiver.Text = ((Outlook.MailItem)inbox.Items[(lsbxMessages.SelectedIndex + 1)]).To;
}
```

Any idea on how to ask for username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask through any dialog box you want to design, then you have to pass the parameters to Outlook through the `NameSpace.LogOn` method. By default you are opening the current users default profile.

Here is a good tutorial (although it only shows logging onto the default profile without asking for a username, its trivial to add your own dialog to get the username/password):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.logon.aspx

Its also important to note that you can't create another instance of Outlook if Outlook is already running, you'll have to get an instance of the running application. *(Well, you can create another "instance" but it does not create a new process and it will use the existing process and loaded profile).* Even then I don't think you can load more than one profile at a time.